# MongoDB C++ driver server-side Query count

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-c

Windows 7 64 SP1 -- 
MongoDB 2.2.0-rc2 --
Boost 1.42 --
MS VS 2010 Ultimate --
C++ driver

I have a function that takes a Query object as a parameter:

```
    someFunction( Query qu )
```

Advantages:

1. Can accept either a Query object or a well-formed BSONObj.
2. Have access to Query helpers such as sort/hint/etc.

Disadvantage:

1. Can't do a server-side count (vs. a client-side count of a batch of results)
     akin to the shell's:

   ```
   nstudents = db.students.find({'address.state' : 'CA'}).count();
   ```

   i.e.,

   ```
   unsigned long long n = c.count("mydb.users", qu);
   ```

   raises the error:

   ```
   cannot convert ... from 'mongo::Query' to 'const mongo::BSONObj &
   ```

So, it was suggested I use a BSONObj as a parameter:

```
    someFunction ( BSONObj qu )
```

Advantages:

1. Can do a server side count.
2. Can convert to a Query and hence use its helpers.

Disadvantage:

1. Anyone using the function must be aware **not** to pass a query 
      as a Query object which is counter-intuitive.

So, my questions are:

Why aren't the helper methods of the Query class implemented in BSONObj? Or, conversely, why couldn't a server-side count method be implemented with the Query class?

Comment: Why pass argument by value instread of reference/const-reference?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that should have been by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned long long count (const string &ns, const BSONObj &query=BSONObj(),
int options=0)
```

So, `count` should receive `BSONObj` (or Base/Derived of/from `BSONObj`).

`Query` has `implicit c-tor`, that receives `BSONObj`.

```
Query (const BSONObj &b)
```

`Query` has public member `obj`, that is `BSONObj`.

Your function can be

```
// i think const Query& qu will be better.
someFunction( Query qu )
```

and for call `count` you should use

```
c.count("mydb.users", qu.obj);
```

Comment: Thank you -- that clears up my misunderstanding. I wish I could vote you useful, but alas I'm under 15.

Comment: @Therefeore: you can also accept an answer if it solves your question :).

Comment: My function is `void printQuery(DBClientConnection &c, std::string &dc, const Query &qu = BSONObj(), std::string sortby = "" )`. But `cursor = c.query(dc,qu.sort(sortby))` raises the error: `error C2663: 'mongo::Query::sort' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer`. I believe this is because of the `const Query` using the member function `sort`. But if I change it to `Query&` without the `const`, then my parameter initialization `= BSONObj()` raises `cannot convert from 'mongo::BSONObj' to 'mongo::Query &'`. Is it really bad form to use a default value for a param? Thoughts?

Comment: @Stennie or ForEveR Could one of you please consider adding [tag:mongodb-c++] tag to this question as I could not create it myself. [tag:mongodb-c] is misleading and I don't belive that the combination of [tag:mongodb] and [tag:c++] cuts it. There already exists [tag:mongodb-csharp], etc. But obviously, you are more aware of what entails tag pollution that I.

Comment: @Therefore: I think [tag:mongodb-c] is a good example of why it would be better *not* to add another tag. There are currently only 9 questions tagged with [tag:mongodb-c], and several of these are C++. Askers may be missing out on potential answers from the much larger group of users following [tag:mongodb] and [tag:c++], unless they also double up on the tags. You can do a search with multiple tags for the equivalent results without the risk of tagging getting too specific  eg: [mongodb c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20mongodb).

Comment: @Stennie Thanks for the advice -- I'll continue to use the mongodb & c++ tags -- it makes more sense by inviting a greater set of eyes on the questions.